# Linq to SQL - Ignore search parameters that are null or zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a search form where the user can enter one to many parameters (Data, Status, Type, ID, Summary, Description) and leave the rest blank.

Here's my Linq to SQL code for my basic search. Is there a way to check each parameter within the Linq for zero, null or empty string?

```
List<RequestStatusModel> objRequestStatus = new List<RequestStatusModel>();
var query = from r in SimCareDB.Requests
            where r.CustomerID == 31       
            select (new RequestStatusModel
            {
                RequestID = r.RequestID,
                RequestTitle = r.RequestTitle,
                DateAdded = r.DateAdded.ToString(),
                DateChanged = r.DateChanged.ToString(),
                RequestStatusID = r.StatusID
            });
```

Thank you!

Comment: why does it have to be 'in' your LINQ query?

Comment: All great answers, this solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be in your linq statement you could just do it with classic if statements.

```
List<RequestStatusModel> objRequestStatus = new List<RequestStatusModel>();
var query = from r in SimCareDB.Requests
            where r.CustomerID == 31
            select (new RequestStatusModel
            {
               //...
            });

if(data != null) //Replace with additional checks, if neccessary
{
   query = query.where(x=> ...);
}

if(status != null) 
{
   query = query.where(x => ...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only filter if certain criteria is passed, you should do something like this

```
var objRequestStatus = new List<RequestStatusModel>();
    var query = from r in SimCareDB.Requests
                where r.CustomerID == 31

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.RequestID))
    objRequestStatus = objRequestStatus.Where(x => x.RequestID == r.RequestID);

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.RequestTitle))
    objRequestStatus = objRequestStatus.Where(x => x.RequestTitle == r.RequestTitle);

//you other filters here
```

This sets up the expression to what you want based on which requests are passed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid all those `if`s, you could do

```
List<RequestStatusModel> objRequestStatus = new List<RequestStatusModel>();
var query = from r in SimCareDB.Requests
            where (r.CustomerID == 31) &&
                  (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? r.RequestID == id : true) &&
                  (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status) ? r.StatusID == status : true)
                  /* And so on */
            select (new RequestStatusModel
            {
                RequestID = r.RequestID,
                RequestTitle = r.RequestTitle,
                DateAdded = r.DateAdded.ToString(),
                DateChanged = r.DateChanged.ToString(),
                RequestStatusID = r.StatusID
            });
```

Comment: All these checks will be translated to the database and executed there.  This may cause unfortunate problems, such as wrong query plan selection or inability to use a favorable index.